# Getting all names from regex

Tags: php, regex

I have made a regex for all kinds of names in a string:

```
$nameRegex = "/[A-Z-ÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ']" .
    "[.A-Z-ÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽa-z-àáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšž']" .
    '+\b(?: \b' .
    "[A-Z-ÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ']?[van|de]" .
    "[A-Z-ÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽa-z-àáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšž']+\b)*/u";
```

I am trying to match all non-standard cases such as:

```
John Doe waves                        | John Doe
Bakary N'Diaye says hello             | Bakary N'Diaye
Iván Aguilar goes well                | Iván Aguilar
Cisteró shot                          | Cisteró
Dan I Soylu shots                     | Dan I Soylu
Mike van der Hoorn with a cross       | Mike van der Hoorn
M.J. Williams takes a shot            | M.J. Williams
Donny van de Beek left foot           | Donny van de Beek
Mike van der Hoorn hello              | Mike van der Hoorn
Artak G. Grigoryan with through ball  | Artak G. Grigoryan
Trent Alexander-Arnold after a break  | Trent Alexander-Arnold
```

However my one is doing a weak job on matching these names - here you can see it in action https://regexr.com/4qgbt.

How can I improve my regex so it catches all the names? (The names are in the beginning of the sentences)

Comment: My name is `John Doe waves`, why don't you accept it? Have a look at https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Matching **all** names is going to be **a lot** more difficult than you think; see https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/

Comment: If the name is guaranteed to be at the start of the string then don't forget to anchor your regex with `^`

Comment: @Toto By `John Doe waves`, meant the guy's name is John Doe.

Comment: The guy's name is, may be, `John Doe` but **my** name is `John Doe waves`

Comment: @senty You missed the point: if someone's name is "John Doe waves", your program will misname them as "John Doe", assuming the "waves" is not part of the name. A more plausible example might be "John Pleads the Third", which could quite reasonably be the third generation of men named "John Pleads", or a headline about someone called John invoking the Third Amendment of the US Constitution. Or perhaps a sentence starting with "May", which may or not be a name...

Comment: As others have mentioned, this is not practical, but `(?:(?:\p{Lu}\p{L}*|van|der?)[.' -]*)+`

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your inputs - I see your point. I'll check other approaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, an expression similar to,

```
^([\p{L} '.-]+?)(?:\s[a-z]+)*\h*$
```

would be OK to look into (with `preg_match_all`) in which there are two groups. The left starting group is a capturing one for the names, and the second one on the right is a non-capturing group to collect everything afterwards, which we are not interested in those.

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/hbrF3O/1/)

#### Test 1

```
$re = '/^([\p{L} \'.-]+?)(?:\s[a-z]+)*\s*$/m';
$str = 'John Doe waves
Bakary N\'Diaye says hello
Iván Aguilar goes well
Cisteró shot
Dan I Soylu shots
Mike van der Hoorn with a cross
M.J. Williams takes a shot
Donny van de Beek left foot
Mike van der Hoorn hello
Artak G. Grigoryan with through ball
Trent Alexander-Arnold after a break
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output 1

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "John Doe waves"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "Bakary N'Diaye says hello"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "Bakary N'Diaye"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "Dan I Soylu shots"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "Dan I Soylu"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "Mike van der Hoorn with a cross"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "Mike van der Hoorn"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) "M.J. Williams takes a shot"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "M.J. Williams"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "Donny van de Beek left foot"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "Donny van de Beek"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(24) "Mike van der Hoorn hello"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "Mike van der Hoorn"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(36) "Artak G. Grigoryan with through ball"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "Artak G. Grigoryan"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(37) "Trent Alexander-Arnold after a break
"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "Trent Alexander-Arnold"
  }
}
```

---

In the input strings, on the left side, no problem seems to be there because each line would start with a name. On the right side though, there are lowercase words in a row with an space in between. Here, we'd try to write an statement to find those, maybe even with a positive lookahead:

```
(?=(?:\s[a-z]+)*\h*$)
```

then with a second statement,

```
^[\p{L} '.-]+?
```

we'd collect the names, and our final expression would become:

```
^[\p{L} '.-]+?(?=(?:\s[a-z]+)*\h*$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2 with positive lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/mzfrs9/1/)

#### Test 2

```
$re = '/^[\p{L} \'.-]+?(?=(?:\s[a-z]+)*\h*$)/m';
$str = 'John Doe waves
Bakary N\'Diaye says hello
Iván Aguilar goes well
Cisteró shot
Dan I Soylu shots
Mike van der Hoorn with a cross
M.J. Williams takes a shot
Donny van de Beek left foot
Mike van der Hoorn hello
Artak G. Grigoryan with through ball
Trent Alexander-Arnold after a break
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output 2

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "Bakary N'Diaye"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Dan I Soylu"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "Mike van der Hoorn"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "M.J. Williams"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "Donny van de Beek"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "Mike van der Hoorn"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "Artak G. Grigoryan"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "Trent Alexander-Arnold"
  }
}
```

#### Method 3

I guess, we can also look at `preg_replace` function, and totally forget about the names and focus on matching the right side boundary of a name in a line, maybe with a simple expression similar to:

```
(?:\s[a-z]+){0,}\h*$
```

or:

```
(?:\s*\b[a-z]+){0,}\h*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tC1RTh/1/)

#### Test 3

```
$re = '/(?:\s[a-z]+){0,}\h*$/m';
$str = 'John Doe waves
Bakary N\'Diaye says hello
Iván Aguilar goes well
Cisteró shot
Dan I Soylu shots
Mike van der Hoorn with a cross
M.J. Williams takes a shot
Donny van de Beek left foot
Mike van der Hoorn hello
Artak G. Grigoryan with through ball
Trent Alexander-Arnold after a break ';

echo preg_replace($re, '', $str);
```

#### Output 3

```
John Doe
Bakary N'Diaye
Iván Aguilar
Cisteró
Dan I Soylu
Mike van der Hoorn
M.J. Williams
Donny van de Beek
Mike van der Hoorn
Artak G. Grigoryan
Trent Alexander-Arnold
```

#### [RegEx Demo 3 for `preg_replace`](https://regex101.com/r/YmDOqy/1/)

#### Method 4:

Maybe, this would be the easiest and fastest way. Here, we'd get the last uppercase letter in a line with a greedy expression, then we'd add a `\S+` or `\S*`:

```
^.*\p{Lu}\S+
```

or,

```
^.*\p{Lu}\S*
```

#### [RegEx Demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/PkoOyu/1/)

or with a numeric quantifier:

```
^.{0,50}\p{Lu}\S*
```

#### [RegEx Demo 5](https://regex101.com/r/LLLuXS/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pLoeLL/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/pLoeLL/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll read through these

Comment: Your one is doing pretty good job. I'll try it with a larger set and try to understand your regex, I'll give a shout if I can't figure out some cases (hope that's alright)